Does glyph of warding cast the spell instantaneously, ignoring the cast time?
My party recently got a job in which we need to defend multiple huts with people inside for a couple of days. There are two wizard in my party, including me, and we both believe just waiting, guarding the huts would be a very boring and tedious process. So I looked up on spells that would do it for us, and I came across Glyph of Warding, which would probably work great for defence mechanisms. We also have explicit instructions not to kill the people trying to intrude, so we just want to trap them. An inverted Magic Circle would work fine for this. The main problem is Magic Circle's cast time is one minute, which won't really work well for trapping people. I've read through the rules of Glyph of Warding, and it doesn't say anything about the cast time. Yes, it does say that if the spell has an area, it'll be centred on the creature, however I'm worried that the intruder could do whatever it is they need to do in that time. I've already asked my DM, and they say unless rules say otherwise, they will make it cast once the cast time is complete.

This question is similar to: Can you store a spell that takes longer than 1 action into a glyph of warding?. It's not identically phrased, but the answers answer your question (because the question implicitly asks how it's handled as well). Storing long casting time spells in a glyph is also related.

@ShadowRanger Yep, that answered it. Thanks!

And this answer to "What ways are there to cast spells faster?" is a fun way to make use of this speed-up.
